# Initialized declarator inside of C++ catch statement

Tags: c++, syntax, language-lawyer, lexer

Do you think that the initialized declarator is a valid lexical structure inside of the caught-declaration part of the catch statement? For example, take a look at the following code:

```
void func( int = 1 )
{
    try
    {

    }
    catch( int a = 1 )
    {
    }
}
```

It compiles fine under latest MSVC 17.0.2 but fails to compile under latest GCC 11.2 (tested using Godbolt.org). I want to know the answer to form a purely lexical understanding about the correct typing of C++ code.

If you read [this cppreference.com article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch) then you find that it says that the declaration should be exactly the same as(*) for function signature arguments, thus putting legitimacy into the MSVC C++ lexer.

* It's not actually the same. The text just happens to distinguish between just a declarator and the initializer part being separate.

Comment: VC 2022 does not compile your code. It does not matter what standard you choose (14/17/20). What would be the point of a default value?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I believe that's a paraphrase of the description of `declarator` and `abstract-declarator`: "part of a formal parameter declaration, same as in a function parameter list".  I think Tumbleweed's answer clarifies what specifically is being referred to as "same as" here.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I edited the question to remove the misclaim. You guys are completely right. There is no mention that the entire typing is the same but the declaration part is which happens to not include an optional initializer by definition. I expected otherwise. Thank you for helping me understand the reference properly.

Comment: @zdf: you are actually right.. What a weird situation. I am so sorry for being wrong about this... This confused me a whole lot where it says "msvc v19.latest": https://godbolt.org/z/xKK4E9zM4

Comment: @zdf: also please take a look at this weird situation where IntelliSense says it does not work but the compiler detects no error... So it does compile, doesn't it? https://green-candy.osdn.jp/external/forumuploads/visual-studio-stuff/catchinitdecl_compile_success_but_intellisense_error_wtf.png

Comment: I do not know what to say. VC has a problem. It might be a configuration problem. You may report it.

Comment: My mistake: I have _Treat warnings as errors_ turned on. So, Intellisense detects the problem (which is weird: I've always assumed Intellisense is using the same compiler and settings as the project) but the compiler is fine with this. I think you should report it to MS as a bug.

Comment: @zdf: I have posted my issue on their official issue tracker over here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Initialized-declaration-inside-of-catch-/1611967

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  It's invalid.

The grammar for the catch clause specifies `type-specifier-seq declarator`.  The `declarator` part of that does not include an initializer. Compare this with the grammar for a function parameter, which *does* allow an initializer:

`attr(optional) decl-specifier-seq declarator = initializer`

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly. You get my accepted answer tag because you have been the fastest!

Comment: @rplgn It's entirely up to you, but in general, it's preferable to mark the answer that was *most helpful* to you as accepted, rather than the answer that was posted the fastest.

Answer (score 2):

first:
No the article does not says it allows initializer in catch statement.

It says to refer to the function specification for

- `type-specifier-seq`
- `declarator`
- `abstract-declarator`

or the `initializer` is a different element.

Second:

An initializer in a catch statement is pointless since a value is required for actualy going into a catch statement. which means that the initializer value would never be used, and it would jeopardize the program flow since the initalization could raise an exception that will at best terminate.

MSVC probably tolerate it out of pointlessness since it cannot affect the program

Comment: You are right! There is a different production for the "initializer" as pointed out by https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function . I was kind of confused so I put this question up. Thank you very much for clarifying this to me.